Error: Cannot find module ..electron\build in angular
I'm trying to convert angular app to msi file using electron and wix to convert.
when i run
C:\my-angular-project\electron> node build installer.js


node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1031   throw err;   ^
Error: Cannot find module 'C:\my-angular-project\electron\build'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1028:15)
at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:873:27)
at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
at node:internal/main/run_main_module:22:47 {   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',   requireStack: [] }

getting the above error,
any solution to fix this issue, Thanks
